# how can I copy a string to the windows clipboard? python 3

Tags: python-3.x, copy, clipboard, pyperclip

If I have a variable  var = 'this is a variable'

how can I copy this string to the windows clipboard so I can simply Ctrl+v and it's transferred elsewhere? I don't want to use anything that isn't that isn't built in, I hope it's possible.

thanks!

Comment: use the `clip` cmd utility. copies it's input to the clipboard

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> def copy2clip(txt):
...    cmd='echo '+txt.strip()+'|clip'
...    return subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)
...
>>> copy2clip('now this is on my clipboard')
```

Comment: May I ask, why the down vote?

Comment: Presumably because of the danger of copying shell code like that. I wonder what `x && rm -rf / ` would do when passed to your function.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman: By that reasoning, one would never use a subprocess call for anything. It is perfectly safe to use a subprocess if the program maintains control of what is called. Indeed, you don't even need to call subprocess to erase the disk. `shutil.rmtree()` would do it or `os.remove()` would do nicely.  I think you are conflating taking user strings or using arbitrary strings and executing code with *those* vs just calling a shell call with a string constructed internally in the program.

Comment: `copy2clip` should do just that, and not erase my disk when a user attempts to copy a dangerous command. Else name it `copy2clip_unless_its_a_shell_script`. I just tried copying `|dir` and got a nice directory listing instead. `hello\nworld` also fails.

Comment: This is *so* inherently unsafe.

Comment: @JohnFrazer: Please elaborate

Answer (score 5):

[Pyperclip](http://coffeeghost.net/2010/10/09/pyperclip-a-cross-platform-clipboard-module-for-python/) provides a cross-platform solution.

One note about this module:  It encodes strings into ASCII, so you made need to perform some encoding/decoding work on your strings to match it prior running it through Pyperclip.

Example:

```
import pyperclip

#Usual Pyperclip usage:
string = "This is a sample string."
pyperclip.copy(string)
spam = pyperclip.paste()

#Example of decoding prior to running Pyperclip:
strings = open("textfile.txt", "rb")
strings = strings.decode("ascii", "ignore")
pyperclip.copy(strings)
spam = pyperclip.paste()
```

Probably an obvious tip but I ran into trouble until I looked at Pyperclip's code.

Comment: Pyperclip now supports Unicode on Windows.