# Python: Can someone explain this code for me step by step?

Tags: python, function, clipboard

I came across [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20577725/953482) when searching for a solution. Unfortunately my rep wasn't high enough to comment so I have started a question for help.

The code below works perfectly and does exactly what I needed it to. Problem I have is aside from the 2 obvious bits def function and call function, I am not sure what it is doing. It seems to add like a `"\n"` newline to the copied string, as when I paste it it does a new line so I want to strip that out. Thanks in advance.

```
#import subprocess - ok
import subprocess
#define a function called copy2clip which takes 1 argument, txt.
def copy2clip(txt):

    #Call CMD and echo (txt) to the clip program (which is not a python program)
    cmd='echo '+txt.strip()+'|clip'

    #Check that the CMD program ran ok
    return subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)

#call our function and pass it this string....
copy2clip('now this is on my clipboard')
```

Comment: `echo` adds a newline; use `echo -n` to echo without one.

Comment: The code is rather dumb, actually; there are better ways to achive what that code does.

Comment: (Be very careful using this... if you pass unsanitized user input to `copy2clip()` the user can execute arbitrary code.)

Comment: This is a valid question, the OP has shown us the effort they've put in to describing their problem, he explained  what it is its doing and has a clear question. It's a basic question, but it's still a valid one.

Comment: Thanks Tankor, I thought so too :)

Comment: Hey! I wrote that code! It is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20577725/298607)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that there is an program called `clip` that reads the standard input and copies that text into the clipboard.

The rest of the program is easy: it calls the shell with the command:

```
echo whatever | clip
```

being `whatever` the text to be copied to the clipboard. `echo` copies the text to the standard input of `clip` and that's all!

But note that this is a terrible way of doing things! Imaging somebody manages to insert the following text into your *clipboard*: `bye ; rm -rf /; echo haha`...

Comment: Ahh ok, so this is firing up a CMD prompt in the background then it echos my text and pipes to clip and clip is something windows recognises and is nothing to do with python??